# How to add buffer in Geomajas

Tags: geoserver, java, geomajas

I am new user to Geomajas. I have created Geomajas plugin and I am using geotools to add shapefiles. and I want to create buffer on layer(road layer, or polygon layer), but I am not getting exact steps to create buffer on Geomajas map, so please help me to to  add buffer to map.